# improving speed of R function (R loop troubles)

Tags: r, performance

I have similar code implemented already that takes advantage of the `cumsum` function in R. I cannot use that in this case because of `some.step.function`.

Besides using the compiler package, does anyone have any advice for significant speed improvments? Thank you!

```
genIPCWNumDenom <- function(data, some.step.function){
  #data is a data.frame
  #some.step.function is a function
  n <- d <- array(0, dim = c(nrow(data),1))
  for (i in 1:nrow(data)){
    n.tmp <- d.tmp <- 0
    for (j in i:nrow(data)){
      wt <- some.step.function(data$X[j] + data$err[i])
      n.tmp <- n.tmp + data$Y[j] / wt
      d.tmp <- d.tmp + 1 / wt
    }
    n[i] <- n.tmp  
    d[i] <- d.tmp
  }
  data$N.wt <- n
  data$D.wt <- d
  data
}
```

EDIT: Thanks for the help so far. Removing the inner loop made the code runnable. I'm hoping to further improve the speed. Here is my loop currently:

```
for (i in 1:nrow(data)){
    err.i <- data$err[i]
    wt <- some.step.func(data$X[i:nrow(data)] + err.i)
    n[i] <- sum(data$Y[i:nrow(data)] / wt)
    d[i] <- sum(1 / wt)
}
```

Comment: is `some.step.function` vectorized? In other words, can you run `some.step.function(c(a, b))` for some scalars `a` and `b` and it will return `c(some.step.function(a), some.step.function(b))`? If yes, you can definitely make this a lot faster by removing at least one of the two `for` loops.

Comment: Yes `some.step.function` is vectorized. To me it is not obvious how to exploit this though
EDIT: the inner loops looks prime for removal due to this

Comment: Thanks. Removing the inner loop made the code runnable. I'm hoping to further improve the speed. Here is my loop currently:
      `for (i in 1:nrow(data)){
        err.i <- data$err[i]
        wt <- some.step.func(data$X[i:nrow(data)] + err.i)
        n[i] <- sum(data$Y[i:nrow(data)] / wt)
        d[i] <- sum(1 / wt)
      }`

Answer (score 0):

You can evaluate `data$err[i]` in the outer loop.

```
for (i in 1:nrow(data)){
    n.tmp <- d.tmp <- 0
    datai <- data$err[i]
    for (j in i:nrow(data)){
      wt <- some.step.function(data$X[j] + datai)
      n.tmp <- n.tmp + data$Y[j] / wt
      d.tmp <- d.tmp + 1 / wt
    }
    n[i] <- n.tmp  
    d[i] <- d.tmp
}
```

Comment: Thank you that's a good point. That's due to negligence on my part. I'm hoping that there's some structural change I can make or some way to vectorize my code

Comment: You can use the `Reduce` function, but there shouldn't be any structural difference between that and your loop.

Comment: I'm not familiar with `Reduce`. Does it typically lead to speed improvements?